# $T(f) = f^\prime$ is a linear transformation on an infinite dimensional without an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $V = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $T : V → V$ defined like $ T(v(t)) = v'(t)$. Prove that $ T(V)$ is equal to $V$ but $T^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Let $x\in V$. Then because $x$ is infinite differentiable we have that it's continuous and then we can integrate it, let  $x_{1}(t)$ be that function, this function is infinite differentiable because it's first derivate is $x(t)$ (whose is infinite differentiable), then $x_{1} \in V$ and then we found a preimage of $x$ so $T$ is bijective. Now, $T$ can't be invertible because is not injective. For example, we have that $T(x^{2}+1)=T(x^{2})$ but $x^{2}+1 \neq x^{2}$.

Is this right?

Comment: Do you mean that "... we found a preimage of $x$, so $T$ is $\textit{surjective}$."? Also, you don't need that part of the argument if all you've been asked to do is show that its not invertible. You have shown that there exists functions $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2+1$ where $g\neq f$ but $T(g)=T(f)$, so yes. you have shown that it is not injective, so it cannot be invertible

Comment: $ker f \ne \{0\} \implies f $ not invertible

Comment: Yes, it is. A nice, simple example that the theorem that an endomorphism on a finite dimensional vector space is an isomorphism iff it is injective iff it is surjective is false in infinite dimension.

Comment: $T$ is not injective so it can't have an inverse